# Better way to detect EOL of a file

Tags: command-line

Is there a quick way to detect the EOL for a file?

I normally just open up the file in [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and check out the status line. I'm **sure** there's a better and quicker way.

I figured a grep might work, but I am not sure if it's the most elegant way to detect the EOLs. I'm specifically focused on detecting the Mac EOL (CR), Windows (CRLF) and Unix (LF).

A a *nix/Bash solution is preferred, but I am interested in other platforms as well.

(Earlier, I answered [a Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/194318/iptables-restore-line-1-failed/194327) that could possibly be an EOL issue, and it got me wondering if there was a quick way.)

Comment: I guess you could get it with `(\r|\n|\r\n)`, but like you say, that's not very elegant.

Comment: What are the 3 possible EOLs?

Comment: Mac (CR), Windows(CRLF) and Linux (LF). I'm sure there's more out there but those are the EOL's I care about. I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`file` (at least with the magic database commonly found on Linux) is an easy way. It won't warn you about mixed-ending files, though.

```
$ file unix mac dos  # the files have line endings matching their names
unix: ASCII text
mac:  ASCII text, with CR line terminators
dos:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Find this one hard to beat.

Comment: 'file' is not a reliable way, at least not without extra parameters for 'file'. On an XML file, it will only output "XML document text", no matter the EOL character sequence (observed on MinGW 1.0.17, 2011-05-30). (I ran into this problem at work.)